# DOCKER_OPTS are reset after system reboot

Tags: linux, docker

I am specifying my TLS certs in /etc/default/docker, like this:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H=unix:// --tlsverify --tlscacert=/etc/docker/mynewca.pem 
                        --tlscert=/etc/docker/mynewcert.pem 
                        --tlskey=/etc/docker/mynewkey.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376"
```

However, every time my Docker host restarts, my settings are overridden with the defaults:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H=unix:// --tlsverify --tlscacert=/etc/docker/ca.pem 
                        --tlscert=/etc/docker/cert.pem 
                        --tlskey=/etc/docker/key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376"
```

This means that I can not communiate with the Docker daemon remotely until I reconfigure DOCKER_OPTS and run

```
sudo service restart docker
```

upstart is starting the Docker daemon, and it looks like the script section of  /etc/init/docker.conf is overriding DOCKER_OPTS, although I can't find where it's getting the defaults from.

```
script
    # modify these in /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB (/etc/default/docker)
    DOCKERD=/usr/bin/dockerd
    DOCKER_OPTS=
    if [ -f /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB ]; then
            . /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB
    fi
    exec "$DOCKERD" $DOCKER_OPTS --raw-logs
end script

# Don't emit "started" event until docker.sock is ready.
# See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6647
post-start script
    DOCKER_OPTS=
    DOCKER_SOCKET=
    if [ -f /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB ]; then
            . /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB
    fi

    if ! printf "%s" "$DOCKER_OPTS" | grep -qE -e '-H|--host'; then
            DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
    else
            DOCKER_SOCKET=$(printf "%s" "$DOCKER_OPTS" | grep -oP -e '(-H|--host)\W*unix://\K(\S+)' | sed 1q)
    fi

    if [ -n "$DOCKER_SOCKET" ]; then
            while ! [ -e "$DOCKER_SOCKET" ]; do
                    initctl status $UPSTART_JOB | grep -qE "(stop|respawn)/" && exit 1
                    echo "Waiting for $DOCKER_SOCKET"
                    sleep 0.1
            done
            echo "$DOCKER_SOCKET is up"
    fi
end script
```

Which

Comment: What is operating system? Why aren't you configuring it in systemd?

Comment: We're using the Azure Docker VM extension, on Ubuntu 14.04. This uses Upstart, rather than systemd

Comment: Looking at upstart has led me to /etc/init/docker.conf - I've added some more info to the question.

Comment: According to the documentation, for upstart it should "/etc/default/docker", you used /etc/defaults/docker -- notice extra 's'. Can you change and try again?

Comment: Sorry,that was a typo in my question. Which documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the docker configuration file that is usually located in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. See here for more information on the configuration:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file

In your case, the `"tlscacert"` option might be of special interest.

Nevertheless, the location of the configuration file may really depend on the OS and distribution (I remember the famous Gentoo `/etc/conf.d/` directory)